# Dyld Library not loaded: Reason: Image not found

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, plot

I know that questions on this have been asked before but I have been unable to resolve my issue using any of their solutions. I am trying to use the DISLIN plotting library on Mac with Xcode. (OS: Yosemite, Xcode Ver: 6.1.1).

I am currently just trying to run a very simple test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> // Required by DISLIN!
#include "dislin.h" // Required by DISLIN! Includes the
// plotting package
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numberOfPoints = 2;
    float x[2] = {0, 1};
    float y[2] = {0, 2};

    cout << x << y << endl ; 
    qplot(x, y, numberOfPoints);
}
```

The error I get when trying to run is:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libdiscpp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/phys239_a2-blbdrjqdqxewuwfvvdxelytbfmzs/Build/Products/Debug/phys239_a2
  Reason: image not found
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

The program compiles just fine, but it will not run. I have installed Dislin with a package from the dislin website (dislin.de) and openmotif via homebrew. I have the project linked with both the dislin and openmotif libraries (located in /usr/local/dislin/ and /usr/local/Cellar/openmotif/2.3.4/lib respectively).

Does anyone have any experience with this? Or, has anyone been able to get dislin working with Xcode before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the point of this whole thing was to get dislin running with Xcode and it looks like I've finally made some solid headway, as I can produce an actual plot. Hopefully there are no new surprises.

In order to make this happen here's what I did.

- Download Dislin (dislin-10.5.darwin.intel.64.tar.gz from dislin.de, in the downloads section)
- Make sure you have an up-to-date installation of X11.  This is where I got it. (http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/)
- Using homebrew, I installed openmotif. This is required by dislin. I used the following command:

`brew install https://gist.githubusercontent.com/steakknife/60a39a32ae84e12238a2/raw/openmotif.rb`

which I found here: https://gist.github.com/steakknife/60a39a32ae84e12238a2

- Then I added the following lines to ./bash_profile

  `export DISLIN=/usr/local/dislin
  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/dislin:/usr/local/Cellar/openmotif/2.3.4/lib/:/opt/X11/lib
  PATH=$PATH:$DISLIN/bin`

I know that the whole DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH thing is maybe not the best, and I honestly don't even know if it actually matters in my installation, but it's working at the moment and I'm not going to try messing with it yet.

- Install dislin. Change to the folder that you downloaded it to and run the command `./INSTALL`
- Now open up Xcode and start a new console application. You will need to make sure that you can link with these libraries properly. In 'Build Settings', to the header search paths I have added `/usr/local/dislin/real64` (there are two 'dislin.h' files. If I don't use the one in this folder, the results I see are garbage.) To the library search paths I have added '/usr/local/dislin/lib`and`/usr/local/Cellar/openmotif/2.3.4/lib`
- In 'Build Phases' add the libraries from the two library folders above.

I then ran the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dislin.h>

double f(double aX)
{
    return aX * aX ; // Function to be plotted
}

int main()
{
    double x[11], y[11] ;
    double del = 0.1 ; 
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++)
    {
        x[i] = i * del ; 
        y[i] = f(x[i]) ; 
    }
    metafl("PDF") ; 
    disini() ;
    name( "X-Axis", "x" ) ;
    name( "Y-axis", "y" ) ; 
    qplsca(x, y, 11) ; 
}
```

And it produced this output: 
[image: Dislin Output]

That's where I'm at. Hopefully this can help someone at some point.